# In case of java var-args, is it possible to determine if the array passed to the method was created from var-args or not?

Tags: java, arrays, variadic-functions

For instance, I have this method that uses var-args:

```
void doSomething(int... args);
```

And I can have 2 different usages:

```
// 1) using an array
int[] data = new int[] {1, 2};
doSomething(data);

// 2) using a sequence of arguments
doSomething(1, 2);
```

Assuming the method doSomething() needs to ensure the passed array is "immutable" from outside, it will copy the array. However, if the caller has passed a sequence of arguments, then there's no reference to the array from outside of the method, therefore we could avoid the cost an array copy.

Is it possible to determine how it was called in runtime?

Answer (score 3):

No. As far as I know, it is not possible to determine which way the caller invoked the method, just that the method was invoked.